# .addTarget method to add an action to a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a function which detects change in a `UITextView` and changes the colour of a few words while the user is editing. Well, to link this function to a `UITextField` I can simply call the .addTarget method. But this does not work for the `UITextView`. I wanted to ask how I should connect the `UITextView` to the function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Basically add "UITextViewDelegate" and do this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    yourTextView.delegate = self

}


func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    //Whatever your code is
}
```

Comment: As you might have seen from my previous question about the colour changing text, this will not work.